# easier way to write loops

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Hello wrote a program that outprints this;

0

01

012

0123

01234

012345

01234

0123

012

01

0

Im pretty sure my method is long and stupid, heres how it looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int first = -1, second = -1, third = -1, fourth = -1, fifth = -1, sixth = -1, seventh = -1, eight = -1, nine = -1, ten = -1, elleven = -1;

while(first < 0){
first += 1; 
printf("%d\n", first);

while(second < 1){
second += 1;
printf("%d", second);
}
printf("\n");
while(third < 2 ){
third += 1;
printf("%d", third);
}
printf("\n");
while(fourth < 3){
fourth += 1;
printf("%d", fourth);
}
printf("\n");
while(fifth < 4){
fifth += 1;
printf("%d", fifth);
}
printf("\n");
while(sixth < 5){
sixth += 1;
printf("%d", sixth);
}
printf("\n");
while(seventh < 4){
seventh += 1;
printf("%d", seventh);
}
printf("\n");
while(eight < 3){
eight += 1;
printf("%d", eight);
}
printf("\n");
while(nine < 2) {
nine += 1;
printf("%d", nine);
}
printf("\n");
while(ten < 1){
ten += 1;
printf("%d", ten);
}
printf("\n");
while(elleven < 0){
elleven += 1;
printf("%d", elleven); 
}
}

return 0;
}
```

if anyone would be kind enough to show me how to do this easier? :)

Comment: Belongs on Code Review.  Too bad I can't vote to migrate it there.  I can however migrate it to a LaTeX specific SO, which is extremely helpful for many questions asked here...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean :)

Comment: There is another site, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, which is intended for questions like this.  This site is about fixing code which doesn't work (or finding a solution to a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I notice that you have a string whose length varies from 1 to 6, and then back, containing the symbols from 0 to its length excluded.

So we can do this with two loops, one ascending, one descending, both nested to get all symbols.

```
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                    printf("%d", j);
            printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 5; i > 0; i--)
    {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    printf("%d", j);
            printf("\n");
    }
```

The second `for` may be replaced with `while(--i)`, since `i` starts from the end of the previous cycle.

Output:

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
01234
0123
012
01
0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just what i asked for :)

Answer (score 2):

These questions that produce triangular-shaped output are always simplest when approaching them mathematically. Consider the absolute-value function (eg: `|x|`, or `abs(x)`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LARGEST_NUMBER (5)
#define MAX_VAL (LARGEST_NUMBER+1)

int main(void) {
   int i,j;
   for(i=0; i<2*MAX_VAL; i++) {
      for(j=0; j<MAX_VAL-abs(MAX_VAL-i); j++) {
         printf("%d",j);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
01234
0123
012
01
0
```

I feel that this is the most mathematically concise approach to this type of problem. I've provided students with this exact problem in the past, and insisted the solution use the `abs()` function so that the function is `factored` as heavily as possible (ie: fewest number of loops, variables, lines of code, and function calls).

Here's the wiki article on the mathematical function itself:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Absolute_value_function

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of N loops use a single loop which resets its counter and limit once the last counter runs past its limit.  When one of the old loops would have ended, insert a newline, set the counter back to -1, and increment the limit (the variable against which you want to test the counter).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            printf("%d", j);

        printf("\n");
    }


    for (i = 4; i >= 0; --i) {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            printf("%d", j);

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using **while loop**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 5

int main()
{
    int j=0, m=0, dec=0;
    while( m>=0 && m<=MAX)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= m; j++)
             printf("%d", j);
        printf("\n");

        if (m==MAX)
            dec = 1; // once hit MAX, chg inc to dec

        (dec)? m--: m++;
    }
}
```